# php for loop and jQuery show/hide method to display number of divs correlated to number of buttons

Tags: php, jquery, for-loop

I've created some kind of loop with PHP and want to be able to display the number of divs based on the number of buttons pressed.

```
  <?php for ($x = 1; $x <= 6; $x++) { ?>
    <button type="button">
      <span><?php echo $x; ?></span>
    </button>        
  <?php } ?>
```

This outputs 6 buttons, then I want to output div:

```
  <?php for ($x = 1; $x <= 6; $x++) { ?>
    <div class="some_div"><?php echo $x; ?></div>
  <?php } ?>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Its simple in jquery.

> Steps to follow :
>
> 1) First you downnlaod jquery latest version library file
>
> 2) Include the file in head tag on the top
>
> 3) Next copy and paste the below code

```
<head>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

jquery

```
$(function() {
  $('.some_div').on('click', function() {
      console.log($(this).text()); // get the number you clicked
      $('.some_div').show();
      $(this).hide();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do this purely with PHP, as you're intending. PHP executes on the server, so by the time the user is clicking buttons, PHP is done executing.

You'll need to use JavaScript for this (or jQuery, as you have the question tagged).

To do this in jQuery, you can do something like this:

```
<?php for ($x = 1; $x <= 6; $x++): ?>
  <button type="button">
    <span><?= $x ?></span>
  </button>
<?php endfor; ?>
<div id="container">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('button').click(function() {
    var selected = !$(this).data('selected');
    $(this).data('selected', selected);

    if (selected) {
      $('#container').append('<div class="some_div"></div>');
    } else {
      $('#container').find('.some_div').last().remove();
    }
  });
</script>
```

Or, if your buttons are tied directly to a specific div:

```
<?php for ($x = 1; $x <= 6; $x++): ?>
  <button type="button" data-index="<?= $x ?>">
    <span><?= $x ?></span>
  </button>
<?php endfor; ?>
<?php for ($x = 1; $x <= 6; $x++): ?>
  <div class="some_div" id="someDiv<?= $x ?>"></div>
<?php endfor; ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('button').click(function() {
    var selected = !$(this).data('selected');
    $(this).data('selected', selected);

    var index = $(this).data('index');
    $('#someDiv' + index).toggle(selected);
  });
</script>
```